# Sign in with LinkedIn API is no longer available on LinkedIn platform?

Tags: linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

Since I could not find this api I tried with the one available. Still I am unable to get the required scopes for posting through api since I am unable to access my profile using Api. Is there an alternate way for posting on linked feed throgh API?

Are there new scopes introduced?